# setId() for programmatically generated Fragment

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, mobile-development

i'm new to android development.

i'm trying to make a notification menu so i made a fragment class:

```
class NotificationFragment {
    private String name;

    public NotificationFragment() {}

    public NotificationFragment(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getName() {return this.name;}

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.notification_fragment, container, false);
    }
}
```

and now i want to load a notification to my screen:

```
private List<int> notifications = new ArrayList<>();

private ConstraintLayer notification_layout = findViewById(R.id.aConstraintLayoutToHoldNotifications);

public load_notification(int i) {
    NotificationFragment cn = new NotificationFragment("TestName"+i);
    FragmentFrame ff = new FragmentFrame(this);
    int last_id = (notifications.size() >= 1 ? notifications.get(notifications.size() - 1) : ConstraintSet.PARENT_ID);
    int toObjectSide = (last_id == ConstraintSet.PARENT_ID? ConstraintSet.TOP : ConstraintSet.BOTTOM);

    int ff_id = View.generateViewId();
    ff.setId(ff_id);
    notification_layout.add(ff);

    ConstraintSet cs = new ConstraintSet();
    cs.clone(notification_layout);
    cs.connect(
        ff_id,
        ConstraintSet.TOP,
        last_id,
        toObjectSide
    );
    cs.applyTo(notification_layout);

    getSupportFragmentManager()
        .beginTransaction()
        .add(notificationLayerID, cn, "UIFragment")
        .commit();

    notifications.add(ff_id);
}
```

now that works fine.

however if i call it again it throws an error `java.lang.RuntimeException: All children of ConstraintLayout must have ids to use ConstraintSet` so i tried to do a bit of debugging and i think that the fragment is what needs an id, but there is no setId() for a fragment class.

***QUESTION:***

```
1) is there a way to set the id of a programmatically generated Fragment?
2) if not, is there a "hack" around this?
3) is there something that i am missing and i don't need an id on the Fragment?
```

***NOTE***

i tried to cut as much code as possible, what is on the post should be the Minimal Executable Example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should answer question 1, it may not solve your problem though.

```
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view =  inflater.inflate(R.layout.notification_fragment, container, false);
        view.setId(View.generateViewId());
        return view;
    }
```

or in you notification_fragment.xml add an Id to the root element, but you most likely will run into duplicate ids problems if you have two notifications present at the same time.

Comment: yeah that works. will that work if i try to use ```fragVariable.getView()```, if the view already exists, will the result of getView() have no id?

Comment: I doubt `getView()` is dependent on the views id, only that its a view. But something like`findViewById(int)` will certainly not work because no id represents the view.